# PYTHON use nother key like "ENTER" key

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox, keyboard, bind

I have a ComboBox in TKinter from Which i can select an option from a drop down menu.
This works with either mouse click or ENTER key.
I want to do the same but with RIGHT key.

```
box1 = ttk.Combobox(root, values=different_values)
def boxenter():
    #quasi ENTER key functionlity

box1.bind("<Right>",boxenter)
```

Comment: What's the problem? It works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind on the *`Listbox`* widget created internally and this internal `Listbox` widget can be accessed by calling TCL command:

```py
box1 = ttk.Combobox(root, values=different_values)

def boxenter(event):
    # simulate "Enter" key
    box1.event_generate('<Return>')

# get the popdown listbox created internally by TCL interpreter
popdown = box1.tk.eval(f'ttk::combobox::PopdownWindow {box1}') + '.f.l'
# call the undocumented _bind()
box1._bind(('bind', popdown), '<Right>', boxenter, None)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Works perfectly!! Cant upvote, reputation 0.

Comment: @Kazkuris You can accept it as the answer.

Comment: Ohh, took me a while to figure that out. Thanks.